# How can I pass a parameter to JasperReport using iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a class with the next code:

```
public Class GenericVehicle{

    private long vehicle_id;
    //Other attributes
    //...

    private List<wheels> myWheels

    public List<Wheels> getNyWheels(int vehicle_type_id){
        //My code to return all wheels from all vehicle with this type
        return List<Wheels>;
    }
}
```

And I need to call this method from a JasperReport using iReport. I am not able to execute it becausse I can not pass the parameter from iReport. How can I do it?

At the moment I am using a report with a subreport with this dataSource Expression. It gives my all wheels of a GenericVehicle (independently if it is car, bus, bike, etc):

```
new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{genericVehicle}.getWheels())
```

But I need to do something like this one, adding the vehicle_type_id parameter to get only the wheels for one specific vehicle type:

```
new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{genericVehicle}.getWheels($P{vehicle_type_id}))
```

I can not change the Java code because it is fixed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you attach the parameter definition for both parameters out of the JRXML?

Comment: No, I can not do it.  Or maybe you can but I am so new with Jasper :-(

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, that can be done:

```
 new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{genericVehicle}.getWheels($P{vehicle_type_id}))
```

Many thanks